# Is there any python module that can turn letters in their respective unicode version?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, module, character-encoding

I've been looking for something that can transform each character into its respective unicode code like this:

```
U+0021 = !
U+0022 = "
U+002D = -
U+0039 = 9
U+0041 = A
U+0042 = B
U+0061 = a
U+0062 = b
U+007E = ~
U+00C0 = À
U+00E3 = ã
U+00E7 = ç
U+00E9 = é
U+00FF = ÿ
U+03A3 = Σ
U+03B1 = α
U+2014 = —
U+201C = “
```

Comment: Do you want to display the character or find the code ? you can just type "\U00000021" this will output the expected character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to import a module.  You can use ord():

```
my_string ="A"
print('U+%04x' %ord(my_string))

#output: U+0041
```